# ImportError: cannot import name 'Topic' from 'first_app'

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey('Topic',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('Webpage',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.date
```

And this is my populate.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

##fake pop script
import random
from first_app import Topic,Webpage,AccessRecord
from faker import faker

fakegen = faker()
topics = ['Search','Social','Marketplace','News','Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    #get the topic for the entry
    top = add_topic()
    #create  the fake data for that entry
    fake_url = fakegen.url()
    fake_date = fakegen.date()
    fake_name = fakegen.name()
    #create a fake new Webpage entry
    webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(Topic=top,url=fake_url,name=fake_name)[0]
    #create a fake access record for that Webpage
    acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg,date=fake_date)[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("population script")
    populate(20)
    print("populate complete")
```

I'm trying run populate.py, but I have an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_first_app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from first_app import Topic,Webpage,AccessRecord
ImportError: cannot import name 'Topic' from 'first_app' (/home/hamid/Desktop/my_django_stuff/first
_project/first_app/__init__.py)
```

Comment: feel like it should be something like `from first_app.models import Topic,Webpage,AccessRecord`

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Hamid : )

if `models.py` is inside `first_app` directory, then you need to change the import line from:

```py
from first_app import Topic,Webpage,AccessRecord
```

To

```py
from first_app.models import Topic,Webpage,AccessRecord
```

Otherwise, the import would be looking for the classes in `first_class/__init__.py`, which is why you're getting that error. For more details you can read up on [Python's import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: @hamid if this answers your question, can you [accept the answer]?